# Open Refine Text Facet Cluster

Tags: python, openrefine

In openrefine when I upload the data, and click on text facet and then clustering. It creates the clusters. Like : Aniket Ghodke and Ghodke Aniket it will suggest to merge them. But is there any way where I can store these values. Like if I merge "Aniket Ghodke" and "Ghodke Aniket" to say "Aniket Ghodke" then can I store these values for my further references. I am ready to use Python or java library too. But is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call most of the clustering function like `ngram(value,4)` or `fingerprint(value)` through GREL. You can store the result in a new column or a facet to explore the result.

[This blog post](http://blog.ouseful.info/2012/11/14/finding-nearly-duplicate-items-in-a-data-column/) explain how to use them.